# Sequelize table name updates

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table in Postgres and for ORM I am using sequelize I need to update the table name so I've tried the below migration for this

```
queryInterface.renameTable('table1', 'table2', { transaction }
```

but for some reason, it's creating a new table with table2 with the same data as table 1 but table 1 still exits with blank data.is this correct behavior of this function so'll add a delete query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works

queryInterface.renameTable('OldTableName', 'NewTableName');

Answer (score -3):

For that use case i normally rely on raw queries:

```
const { sequelize } = queryInterface;

await sequelize.query(
  `ALTER TABLE table1
   RENAME TO table2`,
  {
    type: QueryTypes.RAW,
    raw: true,
    transaction,
  },
);
```

Comment: why raw query but? isn't sequelize is enough for this?

Comment: Sequelize supports this but i'm just used to do that way

Comment: not answer my question I need this working on sequelize

Comment: I think that Sequelize do create that extra table to allow `safe/strong` migrations. 
https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#renaming-a-table
So when you're renaming a table, that's a blocking operation, meaning that if you have a lot of requests being made to the database it will lock that table (which don't happens if it creates a newer one) so i think Sequelize behaviour implement that to allow strong migrations. If its not a problem for you, you can just perform the `raw` query i've showed, or you can do your way, it will create a new table, and you would need to drop that `table1`.

Comment: with raw query too same is happening. can you post full code I think I am making some mistake